# EventListener click function

Tags: javascript, html

I want to return a string value to the p tag once a html button is pressed. I am not sure how to write/format and execute it though. when myFunction returns true and or false para innerHTML = '', will print out a string in the `<p>` tag.

```js
const para = document.getElementById('para');
const palin = document.getElementById('palin');
const sub = document.getElementById('sub'); 


sub.addEventListener('click', function myFunction(str) {
 let re = /[^A-Za-z0-9]/g;
 str = str.toLowerCase().replace(re, '');
 let len = str.length;
 for (let i = 0; i < len/2; i++) {
   if (str[i] !== str[len - 1 - i]) {
       return true;
   }
}
 };
```

```html
<form >
    <input id = 'palin'  type = 'text'></input>


   <button id ='sub'>Submit</button>
   <p id = 'para'></p>
 </form>
```

Comment: There is a closing brace missing. Please fix the syntax errors. To spot them use an editor using syntax highlighting.

Comment: You forgot to ask a question above…

Comment: Check you code first , and then post it . What is str in function ? it is event not string .

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try this

```js
function abc(){

var a = document.getElementById('palin').value;
if(a!=''||a!=undefined){
document.getElementById('para').innerHTML=a;
}

}
```

```html
    <input id = 'palin'  type = 'text'></input>


   <button id ='sub' onclick="abc()">Submit</button>
   <p id = 'para'></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Or check this. As the by default nature of form is submission so try once by removing form tag and also in eventListener the parameter passes will react as an event not as an string.

```js
var para = document.getElementById('para');
var sub = document.getElementById('sub'); 

sub.addEventListener('click', function() {
var str = document.getElementById('palin').value;
 let re = /[^A-Za-z0-9]/g;
 str = str.toLowerCase().replace(re, '');
 
 let len = str.length;
 
 for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
   if (str[i] !== str[len - 1 - i]) {    
       para.innerHTML=str;
       return true;
   }else{
   para.innerHTML="Hello user";
   }
}
 });
```

```html
    <input id = 'palin'  type = 'text'></input>


   <button id ='sub'>Submit</button>
   <p id='para'></p>
```